Replacing connection string to managed Identity for azure blob trigger > Azure function app from VS to azure portal
I have performed the following

Created a simple azure blob triggered function app in visual studio with default setup
Publish into Azure portal and the trigger is set to a different azure blob location

Requirement is to Relplace azure blob connection string with function app Managed identity

I followed this blog which mentions simple setup but in my case the connection string is a different one so I am not sure if this work 

Can you please help to identify

Steps to follow in order to replace with managed identity in Visual studio for this case
Versions of function app and azure blob supports managed identity

I also found this blog which resonates the requirement however I am not sure how to perform this in VS and sync to azure portal for my current function app
thanks

I have updated the answer, can you check it once.

I successfully ran the Blob trigger function locally and in the Azure Function App using DefaultAzureCredentials and Managed Identity.
As mentioned in this MS DOC.

The Blob Trigger manages failures after multiple retries by writing poison blobs to a queue. When using the serviceUri format, the AzureWebJobsStorage connection is required.

If blobServiceUri is specified, you must also include the queueServiceUri in the local.settings.json.

You can use the Blob and Queue service URIs in place of the connection string in the local environment (e.g., Visual Studio).


local.settings.sjon :
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "BlobConnection__blobServiceUri": "https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    "BlobConnection__queueServiceUri": "https://<storagename>.queue.core.windows.net/"
  }
}

Function1.cs :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 
namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
 
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
 
        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("kamcontainer/{name}", Connection = "BlobConnection")] Stream stream, string name)
        {
            using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
        }
    }

Program.cs :
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
 
var builder = FunctionsApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication();
builder.Build().Run();

I have created a Service principle in Azure AD and added the clientID, clientSecret and TenantID to the System Environment Variables  to run the function using DefaultAzureCredentials as shown below.

Add below to your System Environment Variables :
AZURE_CLIENT_ID = <clientID>
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = <clientSecret>
AZURE_TENANT_ID = <TenantID>


I have Enabled the Manged Identity in the Azure Function App as shown below.

I have assigned the Storage Blob Data Owner role to the Service Principal and the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the Function App under Access Control (IAM) in the Storage account, as shown below.

Local Output :
I started running the Blob trigger function and upload a file in the Blob storage as shown below.

The Blob Trigger function ran successfully and retrieved the blob details, as shown below.

I have updated the below in the function app > Environment Variables > App settings and published the Blob trigger function to the Azure Function App, as shown below.
"BlobConnection__blobServiceUri": "https://<storagename>.blob.core.windows.net/",
"BlobConnection__queueServiceUri": "https://<storagename>.queue.core.windows.net/"


Azure Function App Output :
I successfully ran the Blob Trigger function in the Azure Function App and retrived the blob details, as shown below.


Thanks for the elaborate example. I have couple of questions here                                                    1.  Have we make use of user managed identity here and not really the function app system assigned identity?                                                                                                            2. If so how can we make use of just system assigned identity?

Also how you enabled the system assigned identity before it was publish from VS?

@piku I have provided the image of System assigned identity in the answer at identify section in the function app. Can you check it once.

Issue in VS: 1. created a FA from VS 2. selected existing blob n assigned conn name as it's mandatory(myexistingazblob). 3. I added the variables(app cred) of DefaultAzureCredentials in local.settings.json n assigned owner role to existing blob 4. After creating FA locally I see param connection = 'myexistingazblob'. If i remove it (as ur example)the local debugger isnt triggered or keeping it hits the debug and print info the msg as expected but error for connection = 'myexistingazblob' as not assigned.

Question in az portal: Only after publishing to az portal i enable System assigned identity for FA. Also how to take care of the DefaultAzureCred? Is it required in az portal-do i need to create them in FA config variables from UI? or they are for VS only?

@piku DefaultAzureCredential works both locally and on Azure when Managed Identity is enabled in the Function App. No need to add it in portal config, it's for local dev with environment variables.

@piku You need to add the DefaultAzureCredentials in the System Environment Variables in your PC not in the Function App > local.settings.json.

@piku I have updated the local.settings.json and System Environment variables. Can you check it.

i sincerely apprreciate your reponse. Can you please mention how to select the storage account locally and address the issue i mentioned earlier? also the local.settings.json appears  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "", which exacltly we dont want

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@piku I have updated the answer, can you check it once?

i cannot thank you more! it worked perfectly well!

thank you so much for your patience and continous feedback

@piku I'm glad to know that my answer was helpful.

DefaultAzureCredential can obtain credentials of different types, in a number of different ways based on a set of environment variables. But the default options and search order makes it difficult to exclude or enable some of these without requiring code changes.
To allow configuration to specify exactly which type of credential should be used, at least for the types that I wanted to support, I came up with the following;
// default to only allowing managed identities
var options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
{
    ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
    ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
    ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
    ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
    ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
    ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
    ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,

    ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = false,

    Diagnostics =
    {
        IsLoggingEnabled = true,
    }
};

var credentialType = ctx.Configuration["AzureCredential"];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(credentialType))
{
    // set allowed credential types explicitly based on environment variable
    options.ExcludeAzureCliCredential = !credentialType.Contains("AzureCli", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    options.ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = !credentialType.Contains("AzurePowerShell", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    options.ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = !credentialType.Contains("ManagedIdentity", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    options.ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = !credentialType.Contains("Environment", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(options);

